# How can I easily combine the output of grouped summaries with an overall output for the data

Tags: r, dplyr

I've used `group_by` with the `summarise` command in `dplyr` to generate some summaries for my data. I would like to get the same summaries for the overall data set and combine it as one `tibble`.

Is there a straighforward way of doing this? My solution below feels like it has 4X the amount of code required to do this efficently!

Thanks in advance.

```r
# reprex

library(tidyverse)

tidy_data <- tibble::tribble(
        ~drug, ~gender, ~condition, ~value,
    "control",     "f",     "work",   0.06,
  "treatment",     "m",     "work",   0.42,
  "treatment",     "f",     "work",   0.22,
    "control",     "m",     "work",   0.38,
  "treatment",     "m",     "work",   0.57,
  "treatment",     "f",     "work",   0.24,
    "control",     "f",     "work",   0.61,
    "control",     "f",     "play",   0.27,
  "treatment",     "m",     "play",    0.3,
  "treatment",     "f",     "play",   0.09,
    "control",     "m",     "play",   0.84,
    "control",     "m",     "play",   0.65,
  "treatment",     "m",     "play",   0.98,
  "treatment",     "f",     "play",   0.38
  )

tidy_summaries <- tidy_data %>%

  # Group by the required variables
  group_by(drug, gender, condition) %>% 

  summarise(mean = mean(value),
            median = median(value),
            min = min(value),
            max = max(value)) %>%

  # Bind rows will bind this output to the following one
  bind_rows(

    # Now for the overall version
    tidy_data %>%

      # Generate the overall summary values
      mutate(mean = mean(value),
             median = median(value),
             min = min(value),
             max = max(value)) %>%

      # We need to know what the structure of the 'grouped_by' tibble first
      # as the overall output format needs to match that
      select(drug, gender, condition, mean:max) %>% # Keep columns of interest

      # The same information will be appended to all rows, so we just need to retain one
      filter(row_number() == 1) %>% 

      # Change the values in drug, gender, condition to "overall"
      mutate_at(vars(drug:condition), 
                list(~ifelse(is.character(.), "overall", .)))
      )
```

**This the output I want, but it wasn't as simple as I might have hoped.**

```r
tidy_summaries
#> # A tibble: 9 x 7
#> # Groups:   drug, gender [5]
#>   drug      gender  condition  mean median   min   max
#>   <chr>     <chr>   <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 control   f       play      0.27   0.27   0.27 0.27 
#> 2 control   f       work      0.335  0.335  0.06 0.61 
#> 3 control   m       play      0.745  0.745  0.65 0.84 
#> 4 control   m       work      0.38   0.38   0.38 0.38 
#> 5 treatment f       play      0.235  0.235  0.09 0.38 
#> 6 treatment f       work      0.23   0.23   0.22 0.24 
#> 7 treatment m       play      0.64   0.64   0.3  0.98 
#> 8 treatment m       work      0.495  0.495  0.42 0.570
#> 9 overall   overall overall   0.429  0.38   0.06 0.98
```

Comment: It's messy because your end data structure is completely ad-hoc and is not very meaningful. 'Overall' is not a drug, is not a gender, and is not a condition. Having the overall summary in separate additional columns would make more sense for both, coding and analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
tidy_data %>% 
  group_by(drug, gender, condition) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(value), median = median(value), min = min(value), max = max(value)) %>%
  bind_rows(.,
            tidy_data %>%
              summarise(drug = "Overall", gender = "Overall", condition = "Overall", mean = mean(value), median = median(value), min = min(value), max = max(value))
  )
```

This gives:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 7
# Groups:   drug, gender [5]
  drug      gender  condition  mean median   min   max
  <chr>     <chr>   <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 control   f       play      0.27   0.27   0.27 0.27 
2 control   f       work      0.335  0.335  0.06 0.61 
3 control   m       play      0.745  0.745  0.65 0.84 
4 control   m       work      0.38   0.38   0.38 0.38 
5 treatment f       play      0.235  0.235  0.09 0.38 
6 treatment f       work      0.23   0.23   0.22 0.24 
7 treatment m       play      0.64   0.64   0.3  0.98 
8 treatment m       work      0.495  0.495  0.42 0.570
9 Overall   Overall Overall   0.429  0.38   0.06 0.98
```

The code summarizes it via groupings first, and then creates the final summary row from the original data and binds it at the very bottom.

Comment: If you mutate first then bind rows, it will be a slightly shorter call: `td %>% mutate(drug='overall',gender='overall',condition='overall') %>% 
  bind_rows(td,.) %>% group_by(drug,gender,condition) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(value),
            median = median(value),
            min = min(value),
            max = max(value))`

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. My take is basically the same answer as @sumshyftw but uses `mutate_if` and `summarise_at`.

**Code**

```
library(hablar)

funs <- list(mean   = ~mean(.), 
             median = ~median(.), 
             min    = ~min(.), 
             max    = ~max(.))

tidy_data %>% 
  group_by(drug, gender, condition) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(value), funs) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  bind_rows(., tidy_data %>% summarise_at(vars(value), funs)) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.character, ~if_na(., "Overall"))
```

**Result**

```
  drug      gender  condition  mean median   min   max
  <chr>     <chr>   <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 control   f       play      0.27   0.27   0.27 0.27 
2 control   f       work      0.335  0.335  0.06 0.61 
3 control   m       play      0.745  0.745  0.65 0.84 
4 control   m       work      0.38   0.38   0.38 0.38 
5 treatment f       play      0.235  0.235  0.09 0.38 
6 treatment f       work      0.23   0.23   0.22 0.24 
7 treatment m       play      0.64   0.64   0.3  0.98 
8 treatment m       work      0.495  0.495  0.42 0.570
9 Overall   Overall Overall   0.429  0.38   0.06 0.98
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Why did you use the `hablar` package here?

Would `mutate_all(~replace(., is.na(.), "overall"))` not give the same result as `mutate_if(is.character, ~if_na(., "Overall"))` in this instance?

Comment: In this case it works just as well :) However, if you would have had a numeric column with NA replace would change it to data type `character` which could lead to errors that affect other parts of an anlysis. I try to use function that doesnt change column types unless i explicitly tell it to switch type.

Comment: In this case it works just as well :) However, `replace` can be destructive. Imagine that you had a numeric column with NA (not the new mean median...) it would be converted to character since your replacement in `replace` is a character. Implicit converting to new type can have adverse effects on other parts of an anlysis. I try to use functions that do not alter type unless I explicitly tell it to. You can do: `mutate_if(is.character, ~replace(., is.na(.), "overall"))` which is the same as my example but with slightly longer syntax.

Comment: I get your reasoning. Thanks.